# In post-commit file , How run function in php

Tags: php, svn, post-commit

I need to run a function in php file when finished commit. 
If anyone has an idea about it please help with simple example .

Comment: You can do a bash script that does both jobs.

Comment: you could google something like "svn post commit hook"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all comments... I tried and find code..

curl "url"

url means url for the function